# How to get aws kms encrypt response as base64 string in sdk v3. Getting Uint8Array as response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, amazon-kms, aws-sdk-js-v3

I am using `@aws-sdk/client-kms` to encrypt the data. I was getting the base64 string as a response. Now I am getting `Uint8Array`.

```
 const encryptedBlob = await kms.encrypt({
    KeyId: kmsKey,
    Plaintext: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify('data to encrypt')),
  });
```

The encrypted plaintext. When you use the HTTP API or the AWS CLI, the value is Base64-encoded. Otherwise, it is not Base64-encoded. [Mentioned in AWS docs](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-kms/interfaces/encryptcommandoutput.html)

Is there any way to get base64 as response in nodeJs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in [AWS SDK v3 docs Docs](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-kms/interfaces/encryptcommandoutput.html) - Only HTTP API and CLI will get the base64 data. Other mediums will get `Uint8Array` as response.

So, we need some extra data conversion to achieve encryption and decryption using SDK.

```js
const { KMSClient, EncryptCommand, DecryptCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-kms');

const client = new KMSClient({ region: AWS_REGION });

// Encrypt
// Convert Uint8Array data to base64

const input = {
  KeyId: kmsKey,
  Plaintext: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(credentials)),
};

const command = new EncryptCommand(input);
const encryptedBlob = await client.send(command);

const buff = Buffer.from(encryptedBlob.CiphertextBlob);
const encryptedBase64data = buff.toString('base64');

// Decrypt
// Convert Base64 data to Uint8Array
// Uint8Array(response) convert to string.

const command = new DecryptCommand({
    CiphertextBlob: Uint8Array.from(atob(item.credentials), (v) => v.charCodeAt(0)),
  });
const decryptedBinaryData = await client.send(command);

const decryptedData = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(decryptedBinaryData.Plaintext));
```

Comment: That last line can be simplified to `Buffer.from(decryptedBinaryData.Plaintext).toString()`